# How to use Json (C#) to serialize an object ignoring certain properties

Tags: c#, json

This should be easy, but after a day of experiments I more confused.
This would be so useful in test scenarios
Basically I want to easily compare a object created in a test against a what I would expect, but ignoring insignificant properties.
The object is The WPF App and I am refactoring the crucial initialization code, so The scenario would be:

- I want to make a Json copy of the object initialized in the old way (without any unimportant properties) as a json string and saved to a "gold" file
- Run The Test - initialising the object the new way
- Serialise the new object to json string - and to file without the unimportant properties
- Load the gold file -> string
- Compare the two strings
- voila

Essentially a dictionary of top level important properties (nae - values as a string) is what I want. I am not interested in hierarchical complexity as I can do that in the code if I need.
Keeping it simple ...
There are many Json nugets out there and the filtering is "hidden" in the JSon encapsulation.
This is such a useful idea for unit testing, but I am struggling to get a (simple) way to do this. I don't wan't to use attributes in main class - as this is just for a specific test.

I  have looked at many posts and tried various ideas, but it aint getting there.
Please help if you can  thanks

Terry

Comment: Without any code of your class you want to compare it´s really hard to give you any idea, Anyway this site is for helping on specific issues. Your question seemes to be something like "please give me the code for doing this". This is why I vote to close as "too broad".

Comment: *Frequently*, when someone said they tried "lots of things", and they do not cite *any* of those things, they didn't try anything, but want us to think they did.  Please edit your question with some of the things you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using newtonsoft Json.net :
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

You just have to not set the JsonPropertyAttribute

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Person
{
    // "John Smith"
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // "2000-12-15T22:11:03"
    [JsonProperty]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    // new Date(976918263055)
    [JsonProperty]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    // not serialized because mode is opt-in
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is only correct if member serialization is configured to "opt-in" using `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`.   Otherwise the `JsonIgnore` attribute should be used.